# Android Bug while using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a super weird Bug in relation to Retrofit. I have an Interface with the following method

```
    @POST("rooms/{roomName}/join")
fun joinRoom(@Path("roomName") roomName: String, @Body guestData: GuestData): Single<Unit>
```

This method is currently not used but the App crashes. When i put the method inside a comment the App doesn't crash. The only error i receive is inside the next code snippet:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x3525d944 in tid 17490 (RxCachedThreadS)
```

I don't get any further infos when i use doOnError() for example. I know it sounds weird but does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Single<Unit>`. Either change the returned type to something instantiable, or use `Completable`.

Comment: If the method is not in use, then it is most likely a bug in your tooling. Segfaults should not happen with RxJava but sometimes an app may run out of memory or file handles at the wrong time and faults instead of throwing.

Answer (score -1):

I think your functions need to return a `Call<*>`. Try:

```
@POST("rooms/{roomName}/join")
fun joinRoom(@Path("roomName") roomName: String, @Body guestData: GuestData): Call<*>
```